# Functions notifications not working in chat app firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a android chat app and setup the automated notifications using functions in firebase, everything is working fine but when i send a message notifications won't come

Here are the logs in firebase function -

[image: firebase logs]

Here is the index.js file -

```
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {
    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

    if(!event.data.val())
    {
        return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
    }

    const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

    return fromUser.then(fromUserResult =>
    {
        const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
        const type = fromUserResult.val().type;

        const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/token`).once('value');

        return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result =>
        {
            const userName = result[0].val();
            const token_id = result[1].val();

            if(type == "request")
            {
                const payload =
                {
                    data:
                    {
                        title : "You have a Friend Request",
                        body: `${userName} wants to be your friend!`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "com.namandevloper.satyampublic_PROFILE_TARGET_NOTIFICATION",
                        from_user_id : from_user_id
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>
                {
                    console.log(`${userName} (${from_user_id}) sent friend request to ${user_id}`);
                });
            }
            else if(type == "message")
            {
                const payload =
                {
                    data:
                    {
                        title : "You have a new Message",
                        body: `${userName} messaged you!`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "com.namandevloper.satyampublic_CHAT_TARGET_NOTIFICATION",
                        from_user_id : from_user_id
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>
                {
                    console.log(`${userName} (${from_user_id}) send a message to ${user_id}`);
                });
            }
            else if(type == "accept")
            {
                const payload =
                {
                    data:
                    {
                        title : "You have a new friend",
                        body: `${userName} accepted your request!`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "com.namandevloper.satyampublic_PROFILE_TARGET_NOTIFICATION",
                        from_user_id : from_user_id
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>
                {
                    console.log(`${userName} (${user_id}) accepted request by ${from_user_id}`);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Logs in the firebase Functions says - Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

what could be the problem?

Comment: You are using a very old version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase APIs, and probably a very old tutorial.  Use the documentation instead.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {
    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
    if(!event.data.val())
    {
        return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
    }
```

into this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change,context) => {
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

if(!change.after.val())
{
return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
}
```

> The context parameter provides information about the function's execution. Identical across asynchronous functions types, context contains the fields eventId, timestamp, eventType, resource, and params.

Check the guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: It didn't worked it gives this error in logs now - ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: Remove  `if(!event.data.val())
    {` and write `if(!data.after.val())
    {`

Comment: Please read the link `exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
  const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
});`

Comment: no it didn't worked, i guess it needs event because everytime i remove events the firebase gives me error : event is not defined