# Send Push notifications when data changes in firebase reatime database in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am developing a shopping android app with two types of users, End User and Admins. All the orders, data, etc are stored in Firebase's Realtime database. Whenever a new order is created in database, I want devices with admin logins to be notified with a notification that a new order has been created.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You need to use Functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions notifications not working in chat app firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481867/functions-notifications-not-working-in-chat-app-firebase)

Comment: I want certain users of my app to get notifications in their devices when new orders are created in firebase.

Comment: There are two types of users in my firebase. One with root Admins and another with root Users. Users create orders in my app which will create children with an orderid under Orders root. I want Admin users to be notified whenever new orders are created in firebase. This means, for every order created in Orders root, admin users should get notifications.